# gcc - compile, generate assembly with inline source without calling objdump

Tags: gcc, assembly

I'm using `gcc -save-temps` to generate assembly and I added `-fverbose-asm` but that option does NOT generate what I want; it's some weird debug-ish comments.

To get the assembly + inline source, I'm doing `gcc -g` followed by `objdump -S`.

Since `-save-temps` generates the assembly anyway, is there a way to configure it to output the inline source that `objdump -S` produces?

Comment: Try `gcc -S` as indicated in the man page. Note that there is no option to get output similar to `objdump -S`, perhaps you can request that feature.

Comment: Are you just trying to save a step and simplify here, or are you hoping to be able to get `gcc -fverbose-asm -S` output mixed with source?  Note that you can get a very similar effect from the Godbolt compiler explorer's colour highlighting of source + asm lines.  For example, https://godbolt.org/g/SQDMJq.  Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output

Comment: I used `-S -fverbose-asm` but it wasn't the same as `objump-S`. I guess it'll have to be two steps.

Comment: @fuz sounds like that's the answer.  Please put it as the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GNU C compiler (gcc) produces assembly output if you specify the option  `-S` during compilation. Note that this output is not like the output of `objdump -S` in the source code is not interspersed with the assembly.  To get such output, there is currently no way around creating an object file and then disassembling it. Consider filing a bug report if you would like to have such a feature.